# Injecting JS into local Extension file (in new tab)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I spawn a new tab using `chrome.tabs.create()` that tab goes to a page within the chrome extension. 
I then want to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` to inject a JavaScript file into the new tab (enter_content.js). However when I do this I am greeted with the error

> Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url
>   "chrome-extension://adcfbbpepclgchodmdfbijpjhkgcamcg/enter.html".
>   Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

My manifest looks like this

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "myExtension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs",
        "*://*/*"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["generic_content.js"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "run_at": "document_start"
      }
    ]
}
```

What do I need to add to it to allow me to inject the code into the tab?

//UPDATE

To clarify, I have a context menu that when clicked opens a new tab and points it at the local file `enter.html`. the page just consists of an input box and a button. when clicked the button *should* send whats in the input box back to the background script using `chrome.extension.sendMessage()`. But it appears you can't inject a script from the extension into the page (which would allow it to communicate) nor can you directly via inline or seperate js file include anything within the chrome namespace in the `enter.html` code as this violates the default CSP, which if possible I would like to keep as-is.

I have tried editing the CSP slightly but without any effect. I added `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' chrome-extension://adcfbbpepclgchodmdfbijpjhkgcamcg/; object-src 'self'"`
as well as adding the specific pages at the end.

I don't actually have any fully written pages as none of it works so I have no way to test what works in terms of message passing.

Comment: generic_content.js is injected into a tab

Comment: I know it is. I want generic-content to be injected into every tab. I want enter_content.js to be injected into this specific tab

Comment: if the page is withing the extension why would you like to inject content script into it, you can simply add script to the page. BTW, did you try adding `chrome-extension://adcfbbpepclgchodmdfbijpjhkgcamcg/*` in the permissions?

Comment: @UzairFarooq Yeah I tried adding that to the permissions - it says the match is malformed - as well as adding a extra content_script for it but neither work. I also added the page to the web_accessible list and that didn't help. The reason I want to inject it rather than just have the code on the page is because I want to be able to talk to the page from the background script. the default security policy doesn't allow that and I really don't want to change that.

Comment: @wezternator you can communicate between extension pages and background pages using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` or `chrome.extension.getViews(fetchProperties)`

Comment: @UzairFarooq How can I make an new page so as that the background pages knows that it is part of the extension and visa-versa? At the moment i just create a new tab with a relative URL to the page. However when I then use `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` it still violates the security policy _"script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:"._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using the `addEventListener()` to attach onto the buttons so as not to get in the way of the default CSP.

Answer (score 0):

## Problems in your code

- You can not inject script to any of Extension Pages
- `chrome-extension://adcfbbpepclgchodmdfbijpjhkgcamcg/*` is an invalid pattern, the docs are not updated on this.
- Are you invoking `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` from section which is relevant to chrome.* API, the CSP error is cause of this.

## Suggestions

- Why don't you add `enter_content.js` to list of scripts being used by page which is opened, instead of invalid injection.

Comment: 'Why don't you add enter_content.js to list of scripts being used by page which is opened, instead of invalid injection.' I'm not sure exactly what you mean here. Do you mean add the `enter_content.js` into script tags on the HTML page? - If so that won't matter still violates the CSP :( if you mean include it somewhere else in the manifest where exactly would that be? Thanks. @Sudarshan

Comment: @wezternator: Yes i mean adding `<script>` tag to HTML Page, why would it voilate CSP, what is your content in `enter_content.js`

Comment: it uses chrome.extension.sendMessage() to pass the information entered on the page back to the background script. Or thats what I want it to do atleast @Sudarshan

Comment: @wezternator:Can you put your related code of your problem by editing your question, so i can understand it better

Comment: Added more info to bottom of question @sudarshan